# Flutter animatted splash screen can't load pictures

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using animated_splash_screen: ^1.2.0 to build a splash screen for my flutter app. Well the animation did happen, but the image won't load. Here is my code:

```
class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  const Splash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splash: 'assets/pictures/logo.png',
        duration: 3000,
        nextScreen: MyApp(),
        splashTransition: SplashTransition.rotationTransition);
  }
}
```

and this is the exception I got:

> ```
> ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
> Unable to load asset: assets/pictures/logo.png
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:237:7)
> <asynchronous suspension>
> #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:675:14)
> <asynchronous suspension>
>
> Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/pictures/logo.png")
> Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#cb75e(), name:
>   "assets/pictures/logo.png", scale: 1.0)
> ```

Comment: share the assets tag from your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: @AnkitKumarMaurya ok I think I know what is the problem, I didn't add the tag, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't know I have to add a tag to pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
      - assets/audio/
      - assets/pictures/
```

this fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
///Please check your pubsec.yml add your image folder in it like this 

assets:
  - assets/pictures/

///please check in your project assets folder the image file.
///and also check image name should be same as same you define as in stateless widget
class Splash extends StatelessWidget {
  const Splash({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splash: 'assets/pictures/logo.png',
        duration: 3000,
        nextScreen: MyApp(),
        splashTransition: SplashTransition.rotationTransition);
  }
}
```